# Replacing characters inside a bracket using regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a string which goes like:

```
str = "hello <abc123> python <is456> awesome"
```

and I want to replace the characters within brackets with some other characters. Like the above string should give:

```
"hello lock python lock awesome "
```

I tried something like:

```
ss = str.replace("\\<(.*?)\\>", 'lock')
```

but this didn't work. So, how can I do this using regex?

Comment: where did `awesome` go?

Comment: replace() expects two str type params and you are passing a pattern. Incorrect!

Comment: please keep in mind that using `str` as variable name in Python is bad idea, as it is name of type.

Comment: You should use raw strings for regex, as in r'<(.*?)>' instead of "\\<(.*?)\\>

Comment: Unlike in Javascript, the built-in `replace` method of Python strings uses a plain-text pattern. The regex functionality is in the standard library `re` module. While the question has already been answered, you may want to read all the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

Answer (score 3):

You could do a simple `re`gex replace like,

```
>>> import re
>>> str = "hello <abc123> python <is456> awesome"
>>> re.sub(r'<.*?>', 'lock', str)
'hello lock python lock awesome'
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do (combining lookbehind/lookahead assertions with non-greedy matching of `.`):

```
before = "hello <abc123> python <is456> awesome"
after = re.sub(r'(?<=<).+?(?=>)', 'lock', before)
print(after)
```

Output:

```
hello <lock> python <lock> awesome
```

If you don't want the brackets, then `re.sub(r'<.+?>', 'lock', before)` should be fine.

Comment: This does not exclude the angular brackets.

Comment: @DirtyBit yup, I wrote that, then read the question again, then edited my answer to add the last line.

Answer (score 1):

```py
>>> import re
>>> s ="hello <abc123> python <is456> awesome"
>>> re.sub('<.*?>', 'lock', s)
'hello lock python lock awesome'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
str="hello <abc123> python <is456> awesome"
re.sub('\<(.*?)\>','lock',str)
```

**Result:**

```
'hello lock python lock awesome'
```

**Explanation**

1.**\< : <** is a meta char and needs to be escaped if you want to match
    it    literally.
2. **(.*?) :** match everything in a non-greedy way and
    capture    it.
3. **> : >** is a meta char and needs to be escaped if you
    want to    match it literally.

Answer (score 0):

I tried [here](https://regex101.com/r/EVYr6Q/1)
Following regex, and got 2 match groups, one per each `<something>` set:

`regex = r"^.*(<\S+>).*(<\S+>).*$"`

Answer (score 0):

Use below regx:

```
import re
s = "hello <abc123> python <is456> awesome"
result = re.sub(r'\<[^<>]+\>', "lock", s)

print(result)
```

Output:

```
hello lock python lock awesome
```